# Linq To Xml - ReplaceNodes updates number of elements found in original query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I have a linq to xml query which returns 2 nodes. I am attempting to iterate over these nodes and replace their content. However the content that is being added to the XDocument contains nodes which match my query criteria.

```
    protected internal virtual void AddLinkDocument(XDocument content, TaskRequest request)
    {
        var links = content.Descendants("some.link").Where(tag => tag.Attribute("document-href") != null);

        foreach (XElement link in links) //first time through there are 2 links found
        {
             //do some stuff

            link.ReplaceNodes(inlineContent); // after content is added, "links" now in foreach now has many new links found
        }
    }
```

Why is the collection, "links" being updated dynamically each time through the foreach?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does this behavior go away if you add ToArray() to the end of your query?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there are a few factors at play here:

1. The way you've defined `links`, it's going to be re-queried for each iteration of `foreach`.
2. The re-query will search for *all* descendants matching the query (not just immediate children).

My guess is that the iteration block adds some new elements that match the query (ie, contain a "document-href" attribute).

So, I'd suggest trying either:

- adding a `ToArray()` to the end of the definition for `links`;
- or using `Elements` instead of `Descendants` to query only the child nodes of `content`.

Comment: I will try this. However, I don't understand why the query would ever be evaluated more than once since the query is outside the scope of the foreach.

Comment: @Nick it's not a fixed collection, it is an IEnumerable.  Retrieving the actual items is deferred.  Using ToArray forces immediate retrieval of the items.

Comment: Most likely it's due to the use of Descendants. By adding/changing nodes during the iteration, you need to re-evaluate if any of those new children meet the Descendants criteria. Use Elements rather than Descendants if at all possible. This behavior is similar to the issue you see trying to remove an item from a collection while trying to iterate over that collection.